# Java - Append to files in loop or print entire String

Tags: java

The following Code describes my problem:

```
private void transact(TreeSet<BankmanagerTransaction> set) {
        BankmanagerTransaction transaction;
        while(!set.isEmpty()) {
            transaction = set.first();
            execute(transaction);
            printBalance(transaction);
            printLedger(transaction);
            printJustifiedLedger(transaction);
        }
    }
```

Every print function prints to a different File. So I'm wondering what's best practice here.
Is it better to build string and then at the end of the transact method print everything at once, or write to the file line by line?

To make more clear what I'm trying to get at, is the time the file is being edited and therfore used by the program. Because as far as I'm aware I'd have to create a Writer for each file in the transact method and pass it to each of the 3 methods everytime.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Write it the way you think is the clearest.

Comment: When does your set get empty ? nothing seems removed from it in your method.

Comment: This being said, the best option depends on the several factors... the max  number of elements expected from your set (or the global data size), the relation between them and how you're going to process them afterwards....

Comment: You're talking about very small transactions here. Your idea is correct, but your time might be better spent implementing it both ways and trying it out. Personally, I would prefer methods that render/return a string, and then I write them to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases it's the same, but...
Your answer should change with different critereria, i.e. max String length is limited by ram, so in very very lenght cases it is better to write line by line.
But everytime you write (and flush), you are accessing the disk. In remote file locations, if the connection is very unreliable or you have latency, you can build an entire String and write once.
It depends by what is your situation, in general try to make your code CLEAR.